# Slave is not configured or failed to initialize properly. You must at least set --server-id to enable either a master or a slave

Tags: mysql, replication, windows-server, master-slave-replication

I am trying to setup multi source replication. In my slave I have defined following two properties in its configuration file.

```
master-info-repository=table  
relay-log-info-repository=table
```

These entries are needed because I am defining channels in command "CHANGE MASTER TO" as below:

```
change master to master_host="127.0.0.1", master_port=20000, master_user="replication",master_password="password1" for channel="master1";
```

Above command is showing error:

> ERROR 1794 (HY000): Slave is not configured or failed to initialize
>   properly. Yo u must at least set --server-id to enable either a master
>   or a slave. Additional error messages can be found in the MySQL error
>   log.

SERVER ID is clearly defined in config file.

If I don't define those two properties (shown on top) in config file and start slave without "for channel" the it works fine. Only when I try to define multi source it is showing this error.

Error log file contain following entries:

> 2017-01-01T12:41:54.446764Z 0 [ERROR] Error in checking
>   mysql.slave_master_info repository info type of TABLE.
>   2017-01-01T12:41:54.446764Z 0 [ERROR] Error creating master info:
>   Error checking repositories.  2017-01-01T12:41:54.446764Z 0 [ERROR]
>   Failed to create or recover replication info repository.
>   2017-01-01T12:41:54.446764Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to create or recover
>   replication info repositories.

How do I fix this issue?

One thing I came to know that this is related to 5 tables `innodb_index_stats`, `innodb_table_stats`, `slave_master_info`,  `slave_relay_log_info`, and `slave_worker_info`. Even if I delete those tables and then create again then it still shows same error.

I am using multiple instance on a single machine.

Comment: Was `server-id` in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`?